# Годовщина создания сайта – 10 лет!

Tags: обсуждение

Дорогие коллеги,

уже на протяжении 10 лет мы задаем вопросы о русском языке и вместе ищем на них ответы. За это время накопилось немало полезных сведений, которые ежедневно помогают тысячам людей. Хочется верить, что это не предел!

Спасибо вам!

Comment: Десять лет — это эпоха! Aer, у меня возникли сомнения в правильности заголовка. Можно, я задам вопрос на обычном сайте? Это ведь задача *русского языка*, не общая.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова конечно можно! Заголовок новости тоже можно поправить.